# System.ObjectDisposedException in WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to speed up some UWP Bluetooth code I have written to connect to an [O6](https://www.o6app.com/) device. Here is some typical timing measurements:

```
// 20ms
DiscoveredGattDeviceService = DiscoveredBluetoothLEDevice.GetGattService(gattServiceGuid);

// 4,284ms
result = await DiscoveredBluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(gattServiceGuid, BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);

// 444ms
result = await DiscoveredBluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(gattServiceGuid, BluetoothCacheMode.Cached);
```

(N.B. The fastest is marked obsolete.)

From these figures it seems obvious that I should choose the last method, it is much faster than the uncached call and is not marked obsolete. But if I choose either of the two faster calls I hit a problem later in my code with my call to `GattCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync` which throws the exception

> System.ObjectDisposedException

Obviously I've tried making everything in sight static, but it is something beyond my control.

I get the `GattCharacteristic` using this code

```
var accessStatus = await DiscoveredGattDeviceService.RequestAccessAsync();
```

and then

```
var result = await DiscoveredGattDeviceService.GetCharacteristicsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```

and it makes no difference to the error whether I use `BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached` or `BluetoothCacheMode.Cached` in that call to `GetCharacteristicsAsync`

What am I missing? How can I use `GetGattServicesForUuidAsync` with `BluetoothCacheMode.Cached` and end up in a state where I can subscribe to a GATT characteristic?

Comment: To get you a solution I need some more info.
From what point are you starting to measure time?
How do you select you bluetoothLe device?
Is it advertisement watcher or device watcher?
With advertisement watcher I measure from  watcher.Start():
Device found in 2882 ms
Device is connected in 3228 ms
Device service found in 3234ms
Device characteristic found in 3501 ms
Successfully registered; for notifications in 4020 ms

Comment: It's device watcher, but these times are measured from right before the call until just after (using `Stopwatch.Start` and `Stop` and `ElapsedMilliseconds`), i.e. they are not elapsed time since the start they are just the time taken for that line of code.

Comment: For BluetoothLE-devices the device watcher is a absolute no go.  
It takes to long for the watcher to update connection- or pairing status.   
The advertisement watcher is faster and more stable. 
If you already know the BluetoothLE address, service GUID and charactristic GUID,   
than you can scan for device in passive mode to get a callback if the device is in range and advertising so it is connectable. 
If you want I can post a complete simple UWP example as answer.

Answer (score -1):

> System.ObjectDisposedException

The exception that is thrown when an operation is performed on a disposed object.
[ObjectDisposedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

where as you are calling this method

```
public IAsyncOperation<GattCommunicationStatus> WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue clientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue)
```

where the argument
 **GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue**
 Specifies a new value for the ClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptor of this Characteristic object.And as it's enum which have three existing fields.
[GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue fields.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattclientcharacteristicconfigurationdescriptorvalue#fields-)

while you are passing the BluetoothCacheMode enum(Indicates whether certain Bluetooth API methods should operate on values cached in the system or retrieve those values from the Bluetooth device) which has only two fields .
[BluetoothCacheMode fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothcachemode).

Please justify your code and debug out the appopriate argument value for the method which return the object that manages the asynchronous operation, which, upon completion, returns the status with which the operation completed.

As you can use this method

```
public IAsyncOperation<GattDeviceServicesResult> GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(Guid serviceUuid, BluetoothCacheMode cacheMode)
```

which  Returns the GattDeviceServices for the Bluetooth LowEnergy device with the specified UUID.